# Parameterising logic using delegates/actions

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have a bunch of classes implementing a common interface with a single method that takes an object as input. The behavior of the method in each of the classes is identical except that each processes a different field of the object. I am looking to simplify the code. Could I use Actions/delegates? Can some please share some code illustrating how such a scenario can be handled?

This would give a flavor of the code I am dealing with:

```
class A : interface1
{
    int f(List<someObject> x)
    {
         int result =0;
         foreach(var k in x)
         {result += k.field1 ;}
         return result;
    }

}

class B : interface1
{
    int f(List<someObject> x)
    {
         int result =0;
         foreach(var k in x)
         {result += k.field2;}
         return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post some sample code that represents the problem.

Comment: Without more detail, it's hard to give a good suggestion.  Take a look at the Strategy Pattern or Behavior Pattern to see if that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parameter to extract the field you want:

```
int f(List<someObject> x, Func<SomeObject, int> selector)
{
    return x.Select(selector).Sum();
}
```

and call it like:

```
int field1Result = f(list, o => o.field1);
int field2Result = f(list, o => o.field2);
```